# How to pull an existing app/environment FROM AWS Amplify TO an existing local project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

**Background:**

I am working on a shared project which has an Amplify backend environment hooked up (note, it's the production environment). To not affect prod, I created my own AWS account and a new env - for testing/mocking, etc. - based on the config settings already included in the codebase. It worked fine.

Recently though, I switched envs and realized I lost my old working env locally (it's not in `amplify env list`). However, when I log into my AWS Amplify account, the app is still there, and it still has the working env attached.

**How can I pull that working env and all its config and use it in my current project?**

I'm not sure if I'd need to replace the active Amplify app in my project, or just add an env to existing app. I'm scared to `amplify delete` in case I affect the prod env. Maybe a solution would be to `git clone` the project and initialize with the Amplify app from my AWS account? But again, I'm not sure how to get that env from AWS cloud into my local project.

**What I've tried:**

On the Amplify Console page, in my environment, it says this:

```
To continue working on the backend, install the Amplify CLI and make updates by running the command below from the root of your project folder: 
amplify pull --appId oldWorkingApp1234 --envName oldWorkingEnv111
```

but when I run it in CLI this command throws an error, thinking we're in a different app:

```
Amplify appId mismatch.
You are currently working in the amplify project with Id newBrokenApp5678
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to check in the amplify console [image: amplify console]

What happens if you try to create and pull in a new folder? (just to see if it is working fine)

Answer (score 0):

If there is an existing amplify folder in your project, you might need to back  it up and remove it and then retry your pull. That folder holds the current project info which and is the reason why you are saying the error regarding `newBrokenApp5678`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Amplify folder within your project, please remove the `#current-cloud-backend` folder. Before removing, make sure to create a backup by zipping this folder. Once removed, this action should enable you to pull the project.